# Probability that a number is greater than or equal to another one

Tags: probability, arithmetic

What is the probability, given a $n$-bit number $x$, that $x$ is greater than or equal to another unkown unsigned uniformly distributed $n$-bit random number $y$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\mod 2^{32}$? $\mod 32$ means that only bits 0 to 4 need to be examined, so knowing $x_{31}$ to $x_{16}$ is not helpful.

Comment: @Χpẘ Indeed you are right, I will edit this! Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify (and hopefully simplify), you are asking that given a 16 bit unsigned number ($x_{15}x_{14}\dots x_0$), what is the probability that it is greater than or equal to another unknown unsigned _uniformly distributed random_ number ($y_{15}y_{14}\dots y_0$)

Comment: @Χpẘ Well... Indeed it sounds more clear that way ;-) I will edit my question again then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is $\frac{x_{15}x_{14}\dots x_0 + 1}{65536}$. Since dividing by 64k is a right shift the probability is the number with the binary point (analogous to decimal point) to the left of $x_{15}x_{14}\dots x_0 + 1$, with the exception that if $x_{15}x_{14}\dots x_0 = 0xFFFF$ the probability is 1